# C# WPF - DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently struggling with DataGridComboBoxColumn in C# WPF.

I have the class ToolModel

```
class ToolModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Coating { get; set; }
    public bool Thread { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public ToolTypeModel Type { get; set; }
}
```

and the class ToolTypeModel

```
public class ToolTypeModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The data is stored into a database and loaded into my ViewModel

```
class ToolsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ToolModel> Tools { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ToolTypeModel> ToolTypes { get; set; }

    public ToolsViewModel()
    {
        Tools = new ObservableCollection<ToolModel>(ToolModel.GetTools());
        ToolTypes = new ObservableCollection<ToolTypeModel>(ToolTypeModel.GetToolTypes());
    }
}
```

I want to display the data in a DataGrid and attempted to add a DataGridComboBoxColumn to select a ToolType for the correspondending Tool. Therefore I added following xaml definition (wich is already a workaround - but the only way I was able to get it nearly working):

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="ToolsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Tools}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nummer" Binding="{Binding Number}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                    Header="Typ"
                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    SelectedValuePath="Id"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name">

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ToolTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ToolTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

It shows all elements of ToolTypes **but** not the selected one my Tool has a reference on.

Any ideas how I can look up the ToolTypes into the ComboBoxColumn and show the referenced Type as selected item?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelectedValuePath` is the path to a property of the combobox items that will be  bound via the `SelectedValueBinding`. Therefore, `SelectedValueBinding` must bind to a property of the same type.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn 
    Header="Typ"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

If you had a `ToolTypeId` property, you'd use `SelectedValuePath` to bind to that:

```
class ToolModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Coating { get; set; }
    public bool Thread { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }

    //  Like so
    public long ToolTypeId { get; set; }

    public ToolTypeModel Type { get; set; }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn 
    Header="Typ"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ToolTypeId}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

But I don't think that's what you want. I think it's pretty clear you want to get an actual `ToolTypeModel` instance in your `Type` property.

So this should work (I just tested it). Take car, however: Overriding `Equals()` is a little sketchy because it changes the semantics of the C# `=` and `!=` operators for that class, which can bite you.

```
public class ToolTypeModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is ToolTypeModel)
                    ? (obj as ToolTypeModel).Id == Id
                    : false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn
    Header="Type"
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    >
```

(Also, get rid of `Mode=TwoWay` -- that's the default for bindings on that property, you'll get it anyway).

Comment: Thanks! The first way works - but this way I got both Id and reference, I don't think that's a appealing solution. I tried the second one, but it doesn't work for me... there is no selected item.

Comment: @johannesp Oh, whoops -- binding selected item AND selected value should be fine and get you both, but you need to make sure `ToolTypeId` matches `Type` on each `ToolModel` before you populate the grid. With the second version, did you try uncommenting the `Equals()` override?

Comment: still not working :/ SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ToolType}" 
 SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ToolType}" is what I inserted as attributes. I asume you meant with ToolType the 'ToolTypeModel' field, which I called just Type. Either way, doesn't work.

Comment: You must bind to the name of the property. The ToolTypeModel property is named `Type`, right? And the `Id` property is named `Id`. So `SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id}"`

Comment: Okay now I got it! I had to add `SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id}" SelectedValuePath="Id"` - now it works! Thank you!!

Comment: @johannesp OMG thanks for catching that ToolType vs Type typo and fixing it. Sorry!

Comment: @johannesp re: second edit, hang on, I think we've gone badly off the track here. What's there now is already wrong, now that I look at it again: When you try to choose a new `ToolType` for a `ToolModel`, it will change the `Id` property *of the `ToolModel`* to the selected tool type Id -- which I'm guessing you've noticed and you're trying to fix. But if you change the binding path to `Type.Id`, that will change the `Id` property of the selected `ToolType`. Since your ToolTypeModel doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you won't see the bug immediately, which makes things even worse.

Comment: I think it's very likely your `ToolTypeModel` should have private setters for `Id` and `Name`: Those properties should only be set by the constructor; anything else is a bug and you want it throwing an exception so you know the code is doing something wrong.

Comment: wheew -- thanks! I would never have catched this bug! I implemented the way you did in your edit - and figured out it only works if Equals is implemented.